# Incluir um caractere em valores de um excel python

Tags: python, expressões-lambda, formatação

Tenho um dataframe cuja coluna possui 12 caracteres. No entanto a maior parte à esquerda são zeros e no fim dela tenho os valores. Exemplos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando incluir uma vírgula ou ponto antes dos 2 últimos caracteres mas eu não consigo.

`df ['Vlor_Correto'] = df ['Vlor_Correto'].astype(int)` #Já usei para transformar em inteiro

`df ['Vlor_Correto'] = df ['Vlor_Correto'].apply(lambda x: "{:_.2f}".format(x).replace('.', ',').replace('_', '.'))` # E depois este para formatar incluindo 2 caracteres após a vírgula. Mas isto apenas adiciona ,00. e no meu caso não funciona.

Eu quero que os valores saiam desta forma. Obs. Tenho valores como milhar, portanto em alguns casos seria necessário ele entender que isto 000000150259 pode ser um 1.502,59

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tenta fazer um *left strip* de zeros, converter para inteiro e dividir por 100.

Comment: O .astype(int) já faz isso, alterando para inteiro ele já remove os zeros a esquerda. A questão maior está no valor não conter "." ou "," para ser alterado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para transformar a partir da string, antes de fazer o `as_type(int)`:

```
df ['Vlor_Correto'] = df ['Vlor_Correto'].apply(lambda x: float(x[:-2] + "." + [-2:]))
```

Essa forma usa a sintaxe de "slicing" do Python para pegar todo o número do começo até a posição "-2" `[:-2]` : ou seja, o ponto onde ainda falta dois caracteres até o final da string, concatenar um "." e em seguida, todo número de dois caracteres antes do final até o final `[-2:]`. O resultado dessa concatenação é passado para a chamada `float` que transforma a string em um número.

Outra forma é, depois de ter o valor como número, dividir o mesmo por 100:

```
df ['Vlor_Correto'] = df ['Vlor_Correto'].astype(float)
df['Vlor_Correto'] /= 100
```

(O operador `/=` é a divisão inplace, `x /= 10` é o mesmo que `x = x / 10`. Como a coluna é uma Series do Pandas, a divisão por um número já faz a coisa correta que é dividir cada elemento da série e criar uma nova série com os resultados)

Uma nota em paralelo é quanto ao nome da coluna `Vlor_Correto`: é bastante inconveniente de lembrar, de ler e de digitar. A sugestão é, ou usar nomes de colunas em português, com espaços e acentos, para os arquivos de saída já ficarem corretos: "Valor Correto", ou usar nomes "programming friendly" em que você troca espaços por "_", tudo em minúsculas e sem acentos, e de qualquer forma abreviar uma única letra na palavra "Valor" só prejudica a legibilidade (exige mais esforço mental de quem está vendo os dados e de quem está lidando com eles). Mesmo que se economizasse umas 10 letras com esse tipo de abreviação, ainda não valeria a pena.